# Manter dados na textbox do form PHP | HTML

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho um formulário, mas quando eu submeto o formulário, todos os dados nas textboxes desaparecem, quero saber como manter os dados nas textboxes depois de submeter, para que o usuário não tenha que inserir os dados todos outra vez.

```html
<form method="post"> 
<div class="col-md-4">  
<label>Referencia: </label> 
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search" name="referencia"style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome"> 
    </div>
    <div align="right"> 
    <img src="imagens/desenho33.png" align="right" height="250" width="350" > 
    </div>
<br> 
<div class="col-md-4">     
<label>Diametro do Aço (d): </label> 
<input type="text" name="d1" size="6" placeholder="min">
<input type="text" name="d2" size="6" placeholder="max">
</div> 
<div class="col-md-4">
<label>Comprimento total (L0): </label>
<input type="text" name="comp1" size="6" placeholder="min"> 
<input type="text" name="comp2" size="6" placeholder="max">
</div> 
<div class="col-md-4">     
<label>Diametro Exterior (DE): </label>
<input type="text" name="de1" size="6" placeholder="min"> 
<input type="text" name="de2" size="6" placeholder="max"> 
</div>  
<br> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-4">     
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Ordenar por:</label> 
<select class="form-control" name="ordenar" id="ordenar"> 
<option value="diametroaco">Diametro do Aço (d)</option> 
<option value="comprimentototal">Comprimento total (L0)</option> 
<option value="diametroexterior">Diametro Exterior (DE)</option> 
</select> 
</div> 
</div>
</div> 
<br> 
<div align="right"> 
<button type="reset" align="right" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button> 
<button type="submit" align="right" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Continuar</button> 
</div> 
</form>
```

```html
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST)){
        if ($_POST["d1"]<>""){
            $d1=$_POST["d1"];
        }else{
            $d1="0,200";
        }
        if ($_POST["d2"]<>""){
            $d2=$_POST["d2"];
        }else{
            $d2="20";
        }
        if ($_POST["comp1"]<>""){
            $comp1=$_POST["comp1"];
        }else{
            $comp1="1";
        }
        if ($_POST["comp2"]<>""){
            $comp2=$_POST["comp2"];
        }else{
            $comp2="10000";
        }
        if ($_POST["de1"]<>""){
            $de1=$_POST["de1"];
        }else{
            $de1="1";
        }
        if ($_POST["de2"]<>""){
            $de2=$_POST["de2"];
        }else{
            $de2="200";
        } 
//var_dump($_POST);
        $ordenar=$_POST["ordenar"];

        //if(isset($_POST["getproduct"])){
        //$ordenar="nome";
        //}
        switch($ordenar){
            case "diametroaco":
                $ordenar_por="ORDER BY diametroaco";
                break;
            case "comprimentototal":
                $ordenar_por="ORDER BY comprimentototal";
                break;
            case "diametroexterior":
                $ordenar_por="ORDER BY diametroexterior";
                break;
        }

        include ("db.php");
        // $molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp";
           //$molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp $ordenar_por";
        $molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp WHERE (diametroaco BETWEEN '$d1' and '$d2') AND (comprimentototal BETWEEN '$comp1' AND '$comp2') AND (diametroexterior BETWEEN '$de1' AND '$de2') $ordenar_por";
        
         $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$molcomp_query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                $id_mol_comp=$row['id_mol_comp'];
                $referencia=$row['referencia'];
                $diametroaco=$row['diametroaco'];
                $comprimentototal=$row['comprimentototal'];
                $diametroexterior=$row['diametroexterior'];
                $passo=$row['passo'];
                $preco=$row['preco'];
                echo
                "<div class='card mx-auto w-100'>
                    <div class='card-body'>
                            <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-md-1' style='text-align: center'>$referencia</div>
                            <div class='col-md-2' style='text-align: center'>$diametroaco</div>
                            <div class='col-md-2' style='text-align: center'>$comprimentototal</div>
                            <div class='col-md-2' style='text-align: center'>$diametroexterior</div>
                            <div class='col-md-1' style='text-align: center'>$passo</div>
                            <div class='col-md-1' style='text-align: center'>$preco €</div>
                            <div class='col-md-1' style='text-align: center'><i style='font-size:30px' class='fa'>&#xf1c1;</i> <i style='font-size:30px' class='fa'>&#xf217;</i> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ";
           }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deverá preencher esses campos com o dados da requisição `POST` / `GET`
Supondo que você está a usar o método `POST`

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $_POST[nome]; ?>"/>
```

Mesma funcionalidade, apenas mais curto
`<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?= $_POST[nome]; ?>"/>`

Comment: ja adicionei o codigo na pergunta, estou a utilizar o POST, mas nao dessa  forma.

Comment: Está usando AJAX?

Comment: não,mas é necessário?

Comment: Não, não é necessário. Irá depender da sua necessidade. Como está a fazer a submissão dos dados do formulário? Como manipula os mesmos após submeter?

Comment: ja coloquei na pergunta

Comment: A minha resposta resolve o seu problema, qual é a sua dificuldade?

Comment: é que gera um erro:
Notice: Use of undefined constant de2 - assumed 'de2' in (o de2 eu substitui o nome )

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77472/discussion-between-lazyfox-and-edshewa).

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece por que toda vez que vc submete o formulário, a página recarrega, então precisamos fazer uma requisição assíncrona, ou seja fazer um post sem recarregar a página.

Primeiro adicione na tag form os seguintes parâmetros:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="idDoForm">
```

Repare que action="" está em branco, isso impede que ele faça uma ação padrão, nós queremos que ele não faça nada, quem vai trabalhar para nós é um script.

Depois importe a biblioteca Jquery, basta baixar ou importar via CDN:

https://jquery.com/

Depois importe ou crie um novo script na própria página:
(Este script deve ser carregado depois da importação do Jquery)

```
$("#idDoForm").submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'caminhoDoProcessadorPHP', //Exemplo: 'includes/post.inc.php'
        data: $("#idDoForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            //Lembre-se que a variável data vai retornar a resposta do arquivo 'post.inc.php' se vc escrever "echo 'Hello, World!';", a variável data vai conter "Hello, World!", então crie <div id="response"></div> em qualquer lugar da página onde vc quer que essa variável retorne a resposta
           $("#response").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Desta maneira ao apertar o botão "Continuar" o script pega os dados do formulário e passa para o seu arquivo php que processa os dados e dá uma resposta sem recarregar a página.

Comment: não está a funcionar, dá um erro, eu não conheço nada de ajax, não ha outra forma de fazer?

Comment: coloca o erro aqui nos comentários, verifique também o console (F12) e veja se tem algum erro pra colocar aqui também, na aba 'Network' verifique as requisições e veja o arquivo php se tem algum parâmetro sendo passado em 'param'